# Repositioning a DIV with jQuery UI makes it move further bottom right each time it is shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

I have got a little problem with repositioning a div that should serve as an infobox.

I am for example executing an AJAX call and on success I get a message from the server. This message is set as the `div`'s containing text. As these messages have different lengths I have to reposition the div to have it stay in the center of the parent div.

I am trying to achieve this by using `$("#infobox").position({of: $("#parent_field")`. The first time it is shown it is in the exact center. But when it is displayed several times in a row it moves further to the bottom right each time.

All this said here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uweb/4/) for my problem. Just click `Display Infobox` several times to see the problem in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, I think, a consequence of hiding the element, as it runs, the offset co-ordinates are added as an inline-style, then the second and subsequent times the function is run it adds together the original offsets required to the ones that are stored inline.

I don't know if this is relevant but [jQuery UI/API/1.8/Position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position) says:

> Note: jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements.

However:

adding the following, clearing the style attribute, into the function after the fadeout has completed, resets it and stops the compounding offsets.

```
$("#infobox").removeAttr("style");
```

#### [Forked fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/s2srx/)